# covariance with struct constraint

Tags: c#, struct, covariance, value-type

I'm wondering why is such thing allowed after all?

```
interface IProducer<out T> where T : struct
```

if struct is value type then covariance doesn't work because struct is value type. what am I missing here?

Comment: It might be considered [Vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth). Bear in mind that the purpose of the compiler is to produce useful programs - not to be mathematically pure - and so at times it may allow you to make "statements" that contain redundancies or nonsense.

Comment: "out T" in this case will prevent declaring certain members on that interface (like `void Set(T value);`), so you cannot say it's completely useless or has no effect.

Comment: makes sense, so its two separate rules that are not dependent to each other, but intersect of these two rules makes a self contradiction in definition. thanks for the answer, if you could put it as answer I would accept.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at MSDN for [Generic out modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier) there is stated that a typed parameter declared out must satisfy two conditions:

- The type parameter is used only as a return type of interface methods and not used as a type of method arguments.
- The type parameter is not used as a generic constraint for the interface methods.

In terms of code, here is the difference:

```
interface ITest<out T1, T2>  
{
    T1 GetValue();
    T2 GetValue2();
    void SetValue(T1 Arg1); //Compile Error, Condition 1
    void SetValue(T2 Arg1);
    void SetValue2<T3>(int Arg) where T3 : T1; //Compile Error, Condition 2
    void SetValue<T3>(int Arg) where T3 : T2;
}
```

So your T1 cannot be used as an input parameter for methods and neither can it be used as another generic constraint.

Since you have a constraint stating T must be a structure, condition 2 is automatically satisfied.

So the addition of these 2 statements means:

> a structure (`where T: struct`) that can only be used as return value (`out`).

Answer (score 0):

If you declare interface

```
interface IProducer<out T> where T : struct
```

Then you are right that you won't be able to use covariance because it doesn't work with structs, but this is still allowed because covariance is not the only effect of `out` modifier.

It also restricts use of generic type to return type, so it means that you won't be able to add member like this to your interface

```
void MyMethod(T t);
```

This is probably not very useful, but someone could use it to enforce this rule so there is no reason for language to not support this.